# how to apply jquery ui/css to forum field

Tags: jquery, css

How do I apply the nice Jquery UI/CSS to a forum field?  For example, you can do the same to button element by adding .button() to any buttons that you want formatted.  Is there something similar for input field?

---

EDIT:  To specify, I don't mean how to apply my own.  I mean how I apply the nice css styles that JQuery already have to my forum fields.  Like you can apply JQuery styles to buttons, how do I do the same thing with forum inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all of the inputs using jQuery, you can use the following input selector:

```
$('input')
```

To apply a specific style to all of them, you can use:

```
$('input').css('property','value');
```

Or if you wanted to add a custom CSS class to all of the inputs:

```
$('input').addClass('yourClass');
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to apply the styles that jQueryUI uses to style the inputs, then you will firstly want to make sure you include the proper jQueryUI stylesheet. However, this process can be messy as jQueryUI can apply several classes to a single item, for example:

The following are all found on a single button in the jQueryUI example:

```
ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only
```

but if you have the jQuery CSS included, you can perform the same as above to add the styles:

```
$('input').addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ...')
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that I want to add JQuery's styling to my fields, not my own styling.  Please recheck question edit.

Comment: Updated the answer with an edit - I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: Yep, it's a little messy with multiple classes that need to be added, but it works!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('.button').button();
```

And

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

Or for all submit buttons:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').button();
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that I want to add JQuery's styling to my fields, not my own styling. Please recheck question edit.